# Django queryset to get children and grandchildren

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a django model that refers to it's self (in a parent-child-grandchild relationship).

I'm trying to perform a query that will return all the child and grandchild instances of a particular parent.

So for example:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name="children")
```

This relationship goes 3 levels deep - What's the best way to get a queryset with all the children/ grandchildren? I'd like to get them all together so I can order them by date.

Answer (score 6):

I think this should work:

```
from django.db.models.query import Q
Post.objects.filter(Q(parent = post) | Q(parent__parent = post))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/).